# MathJax text broken along several lines in post titles (in review queues)

Tags: bug, design, review, mathjax

I have noticed a problem concerning the use of MathJax in titles of questions that appear in review queues, and this has been happening for some time. Consider, for instance, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4235156/446262). It uses MathJax in its title, and there is nothing wrong with it. However, when I got that same question today in a review queue, its title looked like this:

[image]

( [link to review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1661666) )

Will you please do something about it?

Comment: I can only reproduce this in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: I only use Firefox. In particular, I got this behavior while using Firefox.

Comment: Hm, I use Firefox Nightly 94.0a1 and Chrome 93.0.4577.63.

Comment: I am using Firefox 92.0.

Comment: Able to repro on chrome on Android.

Comment: Same problem with Safari on macOS.