# MathJax layout problems persist in "All actions" tab and review queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

I'm seeing a strange MathJax layout problem on *[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour)*. Here's an example from the "All actions" tab of a user profile, but I've also seen it in the review queues as well.

[image]

This display weirdness is not caused by the user's MathJax input, as you can see from the [post itself](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192242/is-e1-a-mathscrf-t-0-textor-1-rightarrow-e1-a-mathscrf).

[I've reported this problem before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375474/320588), when it manifested in the context of the new layouts for sites' front pages. **This bug is distinct, because it appears on pages that are not front pages, and are not a part of that initiative.**

Davide Cervone suggests "it looks like adding `width:100%` in addition to `display:block` may be necessary for the uses that appear in flex-box settings, like the "Comments" tab on a user's "Activity" page."

I'm using Chrome 97.0.4692.71 for ARM on macOS v12.1 (Monterey).

---

It appears that this issue is more frequent on Math.SE. Some examples:

- [Multiline MathJax on title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34508/multiline-mathjax-on-title)
- [Displays on main question page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34510/displays-on-main-question-page?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Related (perhaps a duplicate report) regarding the "All actions" tab: [Kreiser's answer to "New responsive Activity page"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372605).

Comment: Related (perhaps a duplicate report) regarding the review queues: [MathJax text broken along several lines in post titles (in review queues)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369812).

Comment: This is an issue unique to the "All actions" view and we have a fix incoming. Thanks for reporting!